# How to flatten an object and keeping the same surface area

Tags: mesh

I have an 3D object which I want to flatten out into a 2D template, most important to have the same surface area of 3D and 2D object.

[image: Object] [image: Object] [image: Object]

As I want to make further calculations with that flattened object the "export paper tool" is not an option (need any .ply, .obj, etc. fileformat). I tried with "Loop tools extension -> flatten", scale to one axis (s + z + 0) and with "physics cloth" simulation on a surface but the surface areas were not preserved for any of those.

Cheers and thanks in advance.

Comment: Mathematically, most surfaces can not be flattened while preserving area. The polygonal approximation will be ok, but with cuts. Are they OK? If so, where?